# clients.toJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

Im tryng to filter a result and im getting this error when using toJSON() method.
Am i missing something?

```
const clients = await Database
.select('atendimentos.id', 'nota', 'data_emissao', 'nome_cliente', 'nome_produto', 'data_reclamacao','atendimentos.created_at', 'username')
.from('atendimentos')
.where('atendimentos.id', query)
.join('users', 'users.id', 'id_usuario_fk').first()

return view.render('resultado',{
clients: clients.toJSON()

})
```

Comment: It seems that `clients` does not have a `toJSON` method. Should it?

Comment: Hi There
Yes, i always use toJSON to format my datetime in my frontend.
 But i think im a liitle bit confusing using lucid orm

Comment: And what do you have in `clients`? Is there any result? If you change your current query to `const clients = .select('*').from('users')`, does `toJSON` work?

Comment: I have a search form e and i need to filter a result (a call)

I need to return the call and the user that register it.

If i remove the "clients.toJSON", it will return a object inside array. This way i cant
use toJOSN() method. I need find a way to use lucid to return the filtered call and the user that have resgistered as OBJECT.

As object i can use toJOSN() to format my datatime in frontend

Comment: **first** method return object if you return **array** then try **fetch** method. then not required serialize data because fetch and first method return serialize data

Comment: first() method is already returning JSON why you need to use toJSON()?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya because when i dont use toJSON() my created_at shows "2020-03-16T19:42:13.000Z"  instead 16/03/2020